# django How to review blog comment before publish?

Tags: python, django

I am new in django. I want to review my blog comment before it publish or show in my html template. I am using MPTTModel in my comment model for child parent relationship in my comment section.  I used  BooleanField in my models but it's not working. Right now my html template showing all blog comment when any user submitting comment. here is my code:

**#models.py**

```
class BlogComment(MPTTModel):
      blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
      name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
      email = models.EmailField(max_length=2000)
      comment = models.TextField(max_length=50000)
      created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True,null=True)
      updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,blank=True,null=True)
      is_approve = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**#forms.py**

```
class CommentFrom(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
          model = BlogComment
          fields = ['name','email','comment']
```

**views.py**

```
class BlogDetail(DetailView):
      model = Blog
      template_name = 'blog_details.html'      
      
      def get(self,request,slug):
          blog = Blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
          form = CommentFrom()
          context = {'form':form,
                     'blog':blog,
                   }
          return render(request,'blog_details.html',context)

      def post(self,request,slug):
          blog = Blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
          form = CommentFrom(request.POST)
              
          if form.is_valid():
             comment = form.save(commit=False) 
             comment.blog = blog
             comment.save()
             messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'Your Comment pending for admin approval')
             return redirect(reverse('blog-detail', kwargs={'slug':slug}))
          
          else:
               form()
          
          context = {'form':form,
                     'blog':blog,
                      
                      
                      
                   }
          return render(request,'blog_details.html',context)
```

#html

```
{% load mptt_tags %}
                            
{%  recursetree blog.blogcomment_set.all %}
<p>comment: {{node.comment}}</p>
            {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
               <div class="children pl-2 pl-md-5">
                {{ children }}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
{% endrecursetree %}
```

I also  tried  this query in my views then pass it to context but not seeing any approved comment in my template. `queryset = BlogComment.objects.filter(blog=blog,is_approve=True)` what I am missing???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was put the `queryset = BlogComment.objects.filter(blog=blog,is_approve=True)` in wrong place. after add this queryset inside get method my problem was solved. here is code hope it will help others:

```
def get(self,request,slug):
          blog = Blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
          queryset = BlogComment.objects.filter(blog=blog,is_approve=True)
          form = CommentFrom()
          context = {'form':form,
                     'blog':blog,
                     'queryset':queryset,   
                   }
          return render(request,'blog_details.html',context)
```